# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My navigation suddenly broke down. So there are 3 screens/components, I am using react-navigation to navigate between them. **First screen** is to enter mobile phone number and password, it is sent to api, and some data is saved into state and passed to **second screen**, where i am enter code from sms and send another request to api, if response.status == 200, it goes to **third screen**. Navigation from 1st screen to 2nd works, but from 2nd to third is not. Error occurs when i am going to third screen.

**FirstPage.js**

```
export default class FirstPage extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  text: '',
  password: '',
  password2: ''
}
}
 state = {
uuid: null
}

 getCode(text, psw) {
   fetch('url', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
    body: JSON.stringify({"telephone": text, "password": psw})
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    let uuid = response['data']['id'];
    this.setState({uuid});
    this
      .props
      .navigation
      .navigate('SecondPage', {uuid});
  })
  };

   render() {
return (
  <View
    style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
      <View
        style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 60,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>
        <View>
          <Text>phone number
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            keyboardType='phone-pad'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
            placeholder={"phone number"}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
      <View
        style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 60,
        marginTop: 25,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>
        <View>
          <Text>password</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            keyboardType='phone-pad'
            secureTextEntry
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
            value={this.state.password}
            placeholder={"password"}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
      <View
        style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 60,
        marginTop: 25,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>

        <Text>password2</Text>
        <TextInput
          keyboardType='phone-pad'
          secureTextEntry
          onChangeText={(password2) => this.setState({password2})}
          value={this.state.password2}
          placeholder={"password2"}/>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <Button
      title="getcode"
      onPress={() => this.getCode(this.state.text, this.state.password)}/>
  </View>
);
 }
}
```

**SecondPage.js**

```
export default class SecondPage extends React.Component {
input = React.createRef();
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  value: "",
  focused: false,
  uuid: this.props.navigation.state.params.uuid,
  };
 }

 state = {
  codeConf: '',

 }

   sendCode(uid, code) {
   const body = new FormData
   body.append("authentication", uid)
   body.append("code", code)
   fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body,
    headers: {
      Token: "2f30743e-014d-4f0f-8707-73ae550d8f14"
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(uid + "code is " + code)
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ThirdPage');
    } else {
      console.log(response.status)
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  }

 render() {
return (
  <View
    style={{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FDD7E4',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }}>

    <CodeInput
      ref="codeInputRef2"
      secureTextEntry
      codeLength={6}
      keyboardType='phone-pad'
      activeColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
      inactiveColor='rgba(0, 0, 0 , 0.1)'
      autoFocus={true}
      ignoreCase={true}
      inputPosition='center'
      size={50}
      onFulfill={(code) => {
      this.setState({codeConf: code})
    }}/>
    <Button
      title="send code"
      onPress={this.sendCode(this.state.uuid, this.state.codeConf)} />
  </View>
)
  }
}
```

**ThirdPage.js**

```
export default class ThirdPage extends React.Component {
 render() {
return (

  <View style={styles}>
    <Text>
      Hi there
    </Text>
  </View>
)
 }
}
```

**And finally App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (<AppStackNavigator />)
 }
}

 const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 FirstPage: {
  screen: FirstPage
 },
 SecondPage: {
  screen: SecondPage
  },
 ThirdPage: {
   screen: ThirdPage
  }
  }, {initialRouteName: 'FirstPage'})

   export default createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

I don't really why it happens, because react-navigation says that all then screens from App.js is sent to every screen as this.props.navigation, so I can access them from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have lost scope by not binding your functions, this means that you are no longer accessing the correct value of `this`. You can fix this issue by using arrow functions.

Rewrite your `sendCode` function in the following way, noticing the use of arrow functions

```
sendCode = (uid, code) => {    // <- arrow function
  const body = new FormData();
  body.append('authentication', uid);
  body.append('code', code);
  fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body,
    headers: {
      Token: '2f30743e-014d-4f0f-8707-73ae550d8f14'
    }
  }).then(response => { // <- arrow function
    console.log(uid + 'code is ' + code);
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('ThirdPage');
    } else {
      console.log(response.status);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

And finally update the code in your button to be.

```
<Button
  title="send code"
  onPress={() => this.sendCode(this.state.uuid, this.state.codeConf)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind and pass function definition to onPress prop of Button component in SecondPage.js.

```
<Button
  title="send code"
  onPress={()=>this.sendCode(this.state.uuid,this.state.codeConf)} />
```